# Intellij/AppCode increase selected number value

Tags: intellij-idea, appcode

In Intellij/Appcode, is there any option or plugin I can use so that when I press a certain key(e.g. up arrow) it will increase the selected value by 1 like web developer tool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[String Manipulation](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea) plugin may be what you are looking for, it has the following feature:

- Increment/Decrement selected text. Duplicate line and increment/decrement all numbers found. (Does not work in column mode)

There is also a [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6016).